# I just want to remove the file from directory

Tags: rm

I am trying to remove a file with:

```
ubuntu64@ubuntu:/usr/local/mongodb$ rm /usr/local/mongodb/*
```

But every time it just outputs:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/mongodb/mongodb-linix-x86_64-2.6.4’: Permission denied
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Use sudo

```
sudo rm rm /usr/local/mongodb/*
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

for additional information

Answer (score 1):

The `Permission denied` bit means that you do not have to correct permissions to perform this action. To raise your permissions for the execution of that command try running it with `sudo`:

```
ubuntu64@ubuntu:/usr/local/mongodb$ sudo rm /usr/local/mongodb/*
```